# get all the contents of data lake gen2 folder in a list azure synapse workspace

Tags: pandas, list, azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am brand new to Azure.
I have created a data lake gen2 storage account and a container inside it and saved some files and folders in it.I want to list all the files and folders in azure synapse notebook so that i can process a particular file. I am using this command

```
mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/")
```

but it giving me only one output like:

```
[FileInfo(path=abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/stocks, name=stocks, size=0]
```

I want my answer in a list like:

```
'abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/stocks/',
'abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/stocks/2022-03-06/',
'abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/stocks/2022-03-06/csv_files/',
'abfss://iogen2@demoadlsgen2.dfs.core.windows.net/first/stocks/2022-03-06/csv_files/demo.csv'
```

Apparently when i am using os.listdir it is giving an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

As per the repro from my end, it shows all the files in the folder.

Here is files contained in the folder named sample:

[image]

I'm able to get the all the files contained in the folder named sample:

[image]

If you want to use the `os.listdir` you need to use [file mount/unmount API in Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-file-mount-api).

[image]